# TypeScript NodeJS req.body is null in POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, request

I'm trying to build an backend API with NodeJS and TypeScript but when i send a body in POST or GET request i'm not receiving the result, is a simple backend and i can't understand why the result of my request is null or undefined, even using body-parser.
Someone can tell me why?

src/server.ts

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)   
    return res.send(req.body)
})


const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app runing in port ${PORT}`)
})
```

package.json

```
 {
      "name": "server",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "index.js",
      "type": "module",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "tsnd --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules --respawn src/server.ts"
      },
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.1.2"
      }
    }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   
    "target": "es2017",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                  
    "strict": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true,                   
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You mention post and get. You don’t have a get handler (and get doesn’t support bodies in any case). 

How are you sending your requests? Curl? Postman? It sounds like something is going wrong at that point - possibly you aren’t sending the right Content-Type header

Comment: I'd recommend starting with a GET request (as mentioned by Tom), https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html - please add more detail about how you're sending the request.